# Duplication in Drive letters

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i get device insertion and removal notification from WM_DEVICECHANGE

i get the dbcc_name from the DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE

i get the corresponding drive letter from the DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME

if i insert the device one by one it works correctly

but if i insert two device at a time i get duplication in drive letters

how can i solve it

kindly provide me some ideas

my code snippet

```
if ( DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL == wParam || DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE == wParam )
{
     PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR pHdr = ( PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR )lParam;

     PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE pDevInf;

     PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME pDevVolume = reinterpret_cast<PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME>(lParam);

     switch( pHdr->dbch_devicetype )

     {
           case DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE:
                pDevInf = ( PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE )pHdr;
      updateDevice( pDevInf, wParam , pDevVolume );
                break;

            case DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME:
                  pDevVolume = ( PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME )pHdr;
                  QString aDrive = FirstDriveFromMask( pDevVolume->dbcv_unitmask );
                  break;

      }

}
```

Comment: 4 days ago I wrote a program which I promised you before. It enumerate all drives with drive letters and give additional informations:  VendorId, ProductId, Hardware ID, whether the drive is removable and some more. So it gives the information what you are looking for in some of your previous questions. Could you open one more question with the corresponding title ane I will post you the full source code of this program.

Comment: @Oleg : i have opened a question as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363249(VS.85).aspx) docs mention this piece of info:

> Although the `dbcv_unitmask` member may specify more than one volume in any message, this does not guarantee that only one message is generated for a specified event. Multiple system components may independently generate messages for logical volumes at the same time.

In other words - one message can carry information about multiple volumes added (almost) simultaneously, but that does not guarantee that only one message will be generated for these volumes. You should check `dbcv_unitmask` for more than one volumes.

Comment: is it possible to get dbcc_name from PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME

Comment: No, if you want `dbcc_name`, you need to explicitly register for `DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE` notifications using `RegisterDeviceNotification` and get it from the `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` struct. (Btw, `dbcc_name` is not intended to be human-readable even thouhg it's a UNC-formatted string)